# Laravel Eloquent Query, Many to Many relational data take() not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 'Product' and 'Brand' model Many to Many Relation
I need to fetch data from Brand with limited (5 products ) products so My query is

```
  $brands = Brand::orderBy('order_by', 'asc')->where('status', 1)->with('product')->take(6)->whereHas('product', function ($product){
        $product->take(5);
    })->get();
```

here  `$product->take(5)` not works for me I get all data which are associated with that Brand

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work but you can try this `$product->limit(5)`

Comment: Limit also not work here

Answer (score 1):

you can use the trait: HasEagerLimit:

you can install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

and then in your model:

```
class Brand extends Model {
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
```

and also in Product model:

```
class Category extends Model {
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;


}
```

now : when you load your relation ... it should return the result you desire:

```
$brands = Brand::orderBy('order_by', 'asc')->where('status', 1)->with(['product'=>function ($product){
            $product->take(5);
        }])->take(6)->get();
```

more details in: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit